# How can I perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query like this

```
SELECT Id
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN ErrorId NOT IN (                        
                    ,10                     
                    ,11                     
                    ,12
                    ,13
                    )
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) errorCount
FROM Table 
group by Id
```

I don't like the hardcoded list of ids and I have a simple query that will get me what I want

```
SELECT Id
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN ErrorId NOT IN (
              select ErrorId from Errors where ErrorCategory =  'Ignore_Error'
                    )
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) errorCount
FROM Table 
group by Id
```

However when I try this I get

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

What is my best way ahead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in error message you cannot use `Aggregate` function on top of `Sub-Query`

Here is the correct way to do it

```
SELECT t.Id,
       Count(e.ErrorId) errorCount
FROM   Table t
       LEFT JOIN Errors e
              ON t.ErrorId = e.ErrorId
                 AND e.ErrorCategory = 'Ignore_Error'
GROUP  BY t.Id
```

Another way will be using `Outer Apply`

```
SELECT t.Id,
       Count(ou.ErrorId) errorCount
FROM   Table t
       OUTER apply (SELECT e.ErrorId
                    FROM   Errors e
                    WHERE  t.ErrorId = e.ErrorId
                           AND e.ErrorCategory = 'Ignore_Error') ou
GROUP  BY t.id
```